# Remove multiple elements with same name using removeChild?

Tags: javascript, removechild

I have an element with multiple elements inside. All of the elements inside have the same name. Is there any way to remove them using one function?

(refer to this question for example [Remove multiple children from parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795034/remove-multiple-children-from-parent/6795103)

Comment: remove all elements with, say, a name of "bob" inside of a div? I assume you don't want to touch and "bob"s outside of the theoretical div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that removes the first level children with the specified name for the parent with the specified id.  If you want to go deeper, you can recursively call it on the child elements you get inside (you'll have to add a `parent` parameter as well).

```
function removeChildren (params){
    var parentId = params.parentId;
    var childName = params.childName;

    var childNodes = document.getElementById(parentId).childNodes;
    for(var i=childNodes.length-1;i >= 0;i--){
        var childNode = childNodes[i];
        if(childNode.name == 'foo'){
            childNode.parentNode.removeChild(childNode);
        }
    }
}
```

And to call it:

```
removeChildren({parentId:'div1',childName:'foo'});
```

And a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/U8xkg/) for testing:

Notes:  You can only access the name element dependably in JavaScript when it supported on your element (e.g. NOT on DIVs!).  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570641/javascript-cant-find-div-element-by-name) for why.

**UPDATE:**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/U8xkg/9/)'s a solution using className based on our conversation:

```
function removeChildren (params){
    var parentId = params.parentId;
    var childName = params.childName;

    var childNodesToRemove = document.getElementById(parentId).getElementsByClassName('foo');
    for(var i=childNodesToRemove.length-1;i >= 0;i--){
        var childNode = childNodesToRemove[i];
        childNode.parentNode.removeChild(childNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Weird, i pretty much copied and pasted your code and its not working. All i changed was instead of using onclick for a button, i did on change for drop down. Think that matters?

Comment: Just put my code into your fiddle and it IS working, guess i have some other problem. The error im getting is `document.getElementById("piname") is null
 function()`

Comment: Ohhhh i think i know (from your notes) because i cant apply name to tr. Any workaround without changing the current id? (the ids need to be id1,id2..etc)

Comment: @Jonah Katz You could use a dummy className.  That way, it would simplify getting the nodes that you need to remove.  `var childNodesToRemove = document.getElementById(parentId).getElementsByClassName(childClassNameToRemove)`

Comment: Maybe the name on a tr wasnt the issue because im still getting the same error `document.getElementById("piname") is null function()`

Comment: @Jonah Katz: I've added a className example to my solution.

Comment: @Jonah Katz: do you have an element with id="piname"?

Comment: Yeah i do . `<select onchange="showAccount(this.value)" name="pi_name" id="piname">
                                <option selected="selected" value="empty">--Please Select--</option>


                  <option value="James">James , Lebron
                 </option><option value="Jones">Jones , James
                 </option><option value="Miller">Miller , Mike 
        </option></select>`
(the onchange is for something else)

Comment: @Jonah Katz:  Hmmm...really not sure then.  It's working for me.

Comment: @Briguy36 Got it to work on fiddle! Now need to translate it to my real code.. THANKS!!!

Comment: @Jonah Katz Glad I could help :)

Comment: FINALLY got it to work in FF, but in IE i got this error: `Object doesn't support this property or method` referring to the line
  `var childNodesToRemove = document.getElementById(parentId).getElementsByClassName('foo'); `

Answer (score 2):

**2021 Answer:**

Perhaps there are lots of way to do it, such as [Element.replaceChildren()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceChildren).
I would like to show you an effective solution with **only one redraw & reflow** *supporting all ES6+ browsers*.

```
function removeChildren(cssSelector, parentNode){
    var elements = parentNode.querySelectorAll(cssSelector);
    let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(); 
    fragment.textContent=' ';
    fragment.firstChild.replaceWith(...elements);
}
```

Usage: `removeChildren('.foo',document.body);`: remove all elements with className `foo` in `<body>`

Comment: Thank you for mentioning `element.replaceChildren()`

Comment: `new DocumentFragment().append(...elements);` is an even simpler version of the last three lines.

Answer (score 0):

ok this should be easy.  First get the parent element:

```
var theParent = document.getElementById("notSoHappyFather");
```

then get an array of the nodes that you want to remove:

```
var theChildren = theParent.getElementsByName("unluckyChild");
```

Lastly, remove them with a loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < theChildren.length; i++)
{
  theParent.removeChild(theChildren[i]);
}
```

Comment: 3 things.

1. Excellent humor
2. This doesnt seem to work in IE..
3. I also have an add element that adds more of the element with the name unluckychild. So this function would run more than one time and the i count would need to be rest

Comment: well for some reason I can't seem to get it to work either... which is baffling me atm.  Probably the best path to go is with jquery rather than straight javascript, in which case you can run $("#notSoHappyFather div[name=unluckyChild]").remove().  as long as you run that when ever you want to remove child nodes (even after adding more in or what not), it should work.

Answer (score -1):

A sample of your HTML would get you a more complete answer, but one can fairly easy call DOM functions to get the list of children and just remove them.  In jQuery, remove all children would be something like this:

```
$("#target > *").remove();
```

or

```
 $("#target").html("");
```

And, you can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ZBYCh/

Or, not using jQuery you could also do:

```
document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = "";
```

If you're trying to only remove a subset of the children (and leave others intact), then you need to be more specific how one would determine which children to leave and which to remove.  In jQuery, you could use a .find() select or a filter() selector to narrow the list of children to just the children you wanted to target for removal.