# Remove children by class not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, removechild

I have a script (helped out by @briguy37 [Remove multiple elements with same name using removeChild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795585/remove-multiple-elements-with-same-name-using-removechild/6795938#6795938)) that removes all the elements with a certain class name by using a for loop and using removeChild. Its working perfectly in FF, but in IE, i get the error

```
Object doesnt support this property or method
```

The project can be viewed at: http://jsfiddle.net/U8xkg/31/

The error refers to the line:

```
var childNodesToRemove = document.getElementById(parentId).getElementsByClassName('foo');
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: IE does not support `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: @Jason Oh really? Didnt know that.. does it have an alternative name to get an element based on the class name?

Comment: You could use a library such a jQuery but that may be too much for your needs and a micro-framework library such as [micro-selector](https://github.com/fabiomcosta/micro-selector) could help.

Comment: You can get all elements in the page, and then filter, but this is a bit slow... If you know beforehand what they're element types, you can use getElementsByTagName, then filter, which will be faster

Comment: @Andre I know that the element types are `<td>` and the `name="extraaccount"` can you help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName = function(class_name)
{
    var all = this.getElementsByTagName('*');
    var matchArray = new Array();
    var re = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + class_name + "(?:\\s|$)");
    for (var i = 0, l = all.length; i < l; i++)
    {
        if (re.test(all[i].className))
            matchArray.push(all[i]);
    }
    return matchArray;
}
```

Comment: className property is only IE and getAttribute('class') if for others

Comment: @Maxon Excellent excellent excellent work around! Worked beautifully!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no method getElementsByClassName in IE.

Comment: Oh well. I get im going to have to use getbytagname, even though its invalid to apply a name to a div :/

Answer (score 0):

check whether there is such method - `getElementsByClassName`.
if not, check, whether `querySelectorAll` method is supported.
If, one again, not, you should better use some framework to fetch nodes. 
Especially this code is intended to be cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using any framework in your project (jQuery, YUI, etc...), then do your self a favor and increase your productivity by at least including the [Sizzle library](http://sizzlejs.com/) that adds CSS3 selector capabilities to any browser, yet is quite lightweight and fast.  That will let you just do:

```
var childNodesToRemove = Sizzle(".foo");
```